# getting File java.io.FileNotFoundException: in IntelijIdea but working fine in Eclipse when loading external yaml file in bean in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am facing issue in loading external yml file in to bean in my SpringBoot application. when i am running it in **intellij Idea** version 2019 2.3 , but the same code is working perfectly fine when i am running it directly in **Eclipse**

Below is the code

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;


@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({
    MyWebServicesConfiguration.class
})
public class MyWebServicesConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
      PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

      YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
      yaml.setResources(new FileSystemResource("./conf/sql.yml"));
      propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(yaml.getObject());

      return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }
}
```

main method of Spring boot below

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication(
    exclude = { CassandraAutoConfiguration.class, MongoAutoConfiguration.class },
    scanBasePackages = { "com.this.that.myservices" }
)
@EnableScheduling
public class MyWebServices  {
    public static void main(final String... args) {

        final SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MyWebServices.class);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

Below is the File not found exception i get only when running in intellij Idea but not in eclipse.

```
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'properties' defined in class path resource [com/this/that/MyWebServicesConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer]: Factory method 'properties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./conf/sql.yml
```

EDIT 
Below is the location of conf folder
[image]

Comment: Where is the `conf` directory located relative to your `src` folder?

Comment: Ditch your configuration class and just tell Spring Boot to load the file. Do something like `--spring.config.additional-location=classpath:/conf/sql.yml` when starting.

Comment: @EugenCovaci I have edited the question with location of conf folder,  it is outside src folder , in the same path as src folder.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have tried giving --spring.config.additional-location=full_location_path in program argument in intellij Idea, this also didn't work.  But the way i have given the code in my question , works fine in Eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse has a weird way of including things in the classpath. Nonetheless you shouldn't be doing thing like this in your code, what you now have is 2 `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` (Spring boot includes one as well) which might (and eventually will) interfere with each other. You shold also prefix the path with `file:` als `./` means current location and not the root. So I would expect something like `file:/conf/sql.yml` to work . Regardless of how you use it, althoug I would strongly recommend using `--spring.config.additional-location` as that is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this issue. I had a FileNotFoundException in Intellij while it worked perfectly in Eclipse.

The solution for me was to specify the 'Working Directory' under 'Run/Debug Configurations' because I had a multi-module project (multiple project/modules in 1 project).
If you don't do this, the root folder of the big main project will be the working directory. This is why the paths aren't correct (or at least in my case).

For example:

- MyUltimateParentApplication (the projects root folder and opened in Intellij)

  - MyChildApplication1 (f.e. back-end in spring boot)
  - MyChildApplication2 (f.e. front-end in Angular)

In Eclipse the working directory of 'MyChildApplication1' is 'MyChildApplication1' while in Intellij it is 'MyUltimateParentApplication'. Changing this in Intellij fixed it for me.

While this is probably not the fix for everyone, I still hope this can help other people in the future too.